# Smarter smart pointers

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

I think the concept of a pointer that cleans up after it self like `std::shared_ptr` is cool, but I was wondering if there is a better third party smart pointer out there.

The problem with the `shared_ptr` is that of recursive references.  This occurs when you have something like this:

```
class A{
  public:
  std::shared_ptr<A> other;

  A() { }
};

//Later
std::shared_ptr<A> a = std::make_shared<A>();
std::shared_ptr<A> b = std::make_shared<A>();
a->other = b;  //Memory leak
b->other = a;  //Memory leak
```

Is there a smarter smart pointer out there that can sense when I should have used a weak pointer and doesn't leak (or at least gives a warning)? (After a brief google search I can not find anything)

Comment: Can I ask, why are you doing this? Or is this just a basic example in lieu of something more complicated? With this example you're misusing smart pointers. You wouldn't put `delete this` in a destructor.

Comment: Your class `A` does not compile.

Comment: `A() : self(*this) { }` Huh? What is this supposed to do? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: It is only an example (and apparently not a compilable one).....Not trying to actually use this code

Comment: Okay, but it's hard to understand what the actual problem is, when you demonstrate your problem with an example, saying "This occurs ...", when in fact, nothing occurs, because the example doesn't even compile.

Comment: I'm afraid this example oversimplifies. Programming languages do not strive to prevent you *trying* to shoot yourself in the foot, especially C and C++. They are just tools, just as a hammer that does not prevent you from hitting yourself in the head. What I am trying to say: What is your real world use-case where this will bite you? (In addition to what @BenjaminLindley already mentioned.)

Comment: Are you saying that the presence of the shared_ptr reference to the parent object shouldn't count against the shared_ptr as a reference? If so, how would you ever decide to delete the object?

Comment: @BaummitAugen Edited so it compiles....I am just curious if there is a smarter smart pointer (not actually looking because I need it)

Comment: what is the problem you are trying to solve? if `smart_ptr` leads to cyclic dependency in your case, you can use `unique_ptr` or other types of smart pointers.

Comment: Tbh, without a real world use case, my first response to this still is: Get your your owner relationships straight. I have yet to encounter a problem where some object needs to own its owner. (Maybe there is some A-B-A problem like stuff, but really, show us, there are probably ways around that.)

Comment: @BaummitAugen This could show up in a linked list implementation (where every node has a reference to the next and previous node)

Comment: @DarthRubik - but typically in such a linked list implementation the designer/coder would not create the cycles and instead have the back pointers be either naked pointers or weak pointers (depending on the operations he's going to allow on the linked list).  In other words, with reference counting, it is a design issue.

Comment: This is not a leak and doesn't indicate anything is wrong. Code may come along later and modify either or both of those smart pointers. There is absolutely nothing wrong with having two objects that have smart pointers to each other.

Comment: @DarthRubik Not convinced yet. In a linked list, all nodes are owned by the big list and exist independent of each other. That is, you can  delete any node at any time without more than changing some prev and next pointers, that's kind of the point of a linked list.

Answer (score 3):

A weak pointer is exactly what should be used here.

The fact that `std::shared_ptr` implements basic reference counting, and nothing, more isn't something that was discovered recently. C++ is not a managed language, and has no facilities for automatic garbage collection. As such, circular references via `std::shared_ptr` are problematic. The solution is the weak pointer.

Comment: Yes.  The problem with reference counting as a GC mechanism is that it can't clean up (by itself) cycles. You've got to do it manually.  No smart pointer could detect it for you either _at the point of creating the cycle_  because it wouldn't really know which link was the problematic one.  You _could_ imagine a smart pointer implementation that recorded sufficient information during the program so that at the end of a run (or at checkpoint) it could report on leaks (cycles of objects not pointed to externally).  But I'm not aware of one (and it would necessarily be "debug only").

Comment: It is the purpose of the weak pointer, "std::weak_ptr is used to break circular references of std::shared_ptr. "

Answer (score 0):

The solution is not this:

```
class A{
  std::weak_ptr<A> self;
  public:
  A() : self(*this) { }
};
```

the solution is this:

```
class A : std::enable_shared_from_this<A>
{

  void use_me()
  {
     // say i need to pass a shared_ptr to myself to some other function...
     foo(this->shared_from_this());
  }
};

auto var = std::make_shared<A>();
```

Comment: That really wasn't my question (I am just trying to see about smarter smart pointers, the example was inconsequential)

Comment: when you say "smarter smart pointers" what do you mean? What exactly do you want it to do?

Comment: @DarthRubik - then maybe you should think of a different example ... the current example has the drawback (besides the fact it doesn't compile, apparently) that there exists an "answer" which, plausibly, you didn't know.  Thus, it is confusing.

Comment: I mean one that senses when I should have used a weak pointer

Comment: @davidbak I will post an alternative example

Comment: @davidbak Edited my post (hope this helps)